# partial-screen MapView on BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I am currently working on an application that requires a mapview. The thing is I do not require the screen to be completely taken up by the map view.  I would like to place a few buttons on the bottom of the screen. 
I tried using the VerticalFieldManager to get it working but that didn't work.

This is the code used to call the VerticalFieldManager for the MapView:

```
private VerticalFieldManager startpageTab() 
{
    set=new LabelField("Start Map");
    add(set);
    MapView map = new MapView();
    map.setLatitude(4542349);
    map.setLongitude(-7569792);
    map.setZoom(1);
    // Invoke maps application with specified MapView
    Invoke.invokeApplication(Invoke.APP_TYPE_MAPS, new MapsArguments(map));
    return maptabArea;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

put your buttons in one `FlowFieldManager` and put this `FlowFieldManager` in status,using `setStatus(field);` method.